# Chef: create a directory for a template if it doesn't already exist

Tags: chef, chef-solo

If I have a template being created, how can I ensure that the directory exists? For instance:

```
template "#{node[:app][:deploy_to]}/#{node[:app][:name]}/shared/config/database.yml" do
  source 'database.yml.erb'
  owner node[:user][:username]
  group node[:user][:username]
  mode 0644
  variables({
    :environment => node[:app][:environment],
    :adapter => node[:database][:adapter],
    :database => node[:database][:name],
    :username => node[:database][:username],
    :password => node[:database][:password],
    :host => node[:database][:host]
  })
end
```

This fails since `/var/www/example/shared/config` does not exist for `database.yml` to be copied into. I'm thinking of how puppet allows you to "ensure" a directory exists.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [directory resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_directory.html) to create the directory before creating the template.  The trick is to also specify the `recursive` attribute otherwise the action will fail unless all parts of the directory but the last exist already.

```
config_dir = "#{node[:app][:deploy_to]}/#{node[:app][:name]}/shared/config"

directory config_dir do
  owner node[:user][:username]
  group node[:user][:username]
  recursive true
end

template "#{config_dir}/database.yml" do
  source "database.yml.erb"
  ...
end
```

Note that the `owner` and `group` of the directory resource are only applied to the leaf directory when it's being created.  The permissions of the rest of the directory are undefined, but will probably be root.root and whatever your umask is.

Comment: That's why I dislike the `recursive` option ;-)

Comment: Yeah - me too.  It just doesn't feel very Chef-y either having to specify each level or leave it all up to defaults.

Comment: link broken new link for directory resource is this https://docs.chef.io/resource_directory.html

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of any other way than using the `directory` resource before the `template` resource:

```
directory "#{node[:app][:deploy_to]}/#{node[:app][:name]}/shared/config/
  owner node[:user][:username]
  group node[:user][:username]
end
```